# Query SQL database with JSON Value

Tags: json, sql-server

Here is my JSON:

```
[{"Key":"schedulerItemType","Value":"schedule"},{"Key":"scheduleId","Value":"82"},{"Key":"scheduleEventId","Value":"-1"},{"Key":"scheduleTypeId","Value":"2"},{"Key":"scheduleName","Value":"Fixed Schedule"},{"Key":"moduleId","Value":"5"}]
```

I want to query the database by FileMetadata column

I've tried this:

```
  SELECT * FROM FileSystemItems WHERE JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, '$.Key') = 'scheduleId' and JSON_VALUE(FileMetadata, '$.Value') = '82'
```

but it doesn't work!

I had it working with just a dictionary key/value pair, but I needed to return the data differently, so I am adding it with key and value into the json now.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sample data given you'd have to supply an array index to query the 1th element (0-based array indexes), e.g.:

```sql
 select *
 from dbo.FileSystemItems
 where json_value(FileMetadata, '$[1].Key') = 'scheduleId'
 and json_value(FileMetadata, '$[1].Value') = '82'
```

If the `scheduleId` key can appear at arbitrary positions in the array then you can restructure the query to use [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) instead, e.g.:

```sql
select *
from dbo.FileSystemItems
cross apply openjson(FileMetadata) with (
  [Key] nvarchar(50) N'$.Key',
  Value nvarchar(50) N'$.Value'
) j
where j.[Key] = N'scheduleId'
and j.Value = N'82'
```

Comment: That was it!!! Thank you :-)  I used the first item. It should always be at the 1 index (2nd item)